# Pass 'file' command results to find command

Tags: files, find

I was trying to get through level 4 of Over the Wire - Bandit wargame.
The level requires you to look for a password stored in the only human-readable file in a folder.

Now, the files are only a few, so what I did was, for each file, check its type with the `file` command, and open the ASCII one as soon as I found it.
I was wondering if there is a way to pass `file` results to the `find` command, in order to make this search automatically.

(Feels like a really trivial question, but still I couldn't find an answer).

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is find supposed to do here, look for the password?

Comment: try `file * | grep -i text`.   the text file may not be ascii - it may be utf-8 or utf-16, and that will at least narrow down the list of possible files.  then view them with, e.g. `less`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -I` ignores non-ASCII files. This is a non-standard option, but implemented by many `grep`s.

```
find thefolder -type f -exec grep -q -I . {} ';' -print
```

This would list all files in or below `thefolder` that were ASCII (according to `grep`) and non-empty (we're asking `grep` to look for a single character).

With GNU `find`, you can easily also ignore files that you don't have read access to:

```
find thefolder -type f -readable -exec grep -q -I . {} ';' -print
```

The only difference here is that you would avoid a few "permission denied" errors.

With `grep` implementation that can do recursive grepping:

```
grep -rlI . thefolder
```

---

Using `file` as you suggest:

```
find thefolder -type f -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -qi text' sh {} ';' -print
```

This is very much slower than the first solution, but works if you trust `file` to work its magic correctly.

Ever so slightly quicker (only executes `sh` once or a few times):

```
find thefolder -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if file "$pathname" | grep -qi text; then
            printf "%s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```